# Setting BOLD to a custom font in iTextPDF

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I need to use a particular font to make a document because it contains specia charactesrs such as **"Đ"** that are not supported by the normal fonts iText comes with.

So, I made this:

```
BaseFont CROACIA = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\FreeSans.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

Font CROATA = new Font(CROACIA, 12);
```

It works fine and my **"Đ"**  problem is solved, the thing is that I cant set it to be bold

I tried to make a different font with "BOLD" setting like this_

```
Font CROATABOLD = new Font(CROACIA, 12, BOLD);
```

The code does not seems erroneous but when I apply it to a paragraph it just not work, the font seems as normal as usual

Comment: What is bold here, `Font.BOLD` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

FreeSans and FreeSansBold are *different fonts* of the *same family*. You provide a path to the `FreeSans.ttf` font program and as a result iText can use the regular font in the FreeSans family. If you want to use the bold font, you need to provide a path to `FreeSansBold.ttf` which is a different font program for a font in the same family.

This is shown in the [FreeSansBold](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/using-fonts#1572-freesansbold.java) example:

```
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";
public static final String FONTBOLD = "resources/fonts/FreeSansBold.ttf";

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font = new Font(bf, 12);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("FreeSans regular: \u0110", font);
    document.add(p);
    BaseFont bfbold = BaseFont.createFont(FONTBOLD, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font bold = new Font(bfbold, 12);
    p = new Paragraph("FreeSans bold: \u0110", bold);
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}
```

We have two different fonts [FreeSans.ttf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf) and [FreeSansBold.ttf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/fonts/FreeSansBold.ttf) of the same family. One is the regular font; the other one is the bold font. If you look at the document properties of the result, [free_sans_bold.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/fonts/cmp_free_sans_bold.pdf), you clearly see that two different fonts are at play:

[image]